# Heroku hosted RoR site with CloudFlare ssl not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I am in desperate need of help! I have a Ruby on Rails site hosted on Heroku.  The site works fine withe the heroku app address.  I am trying to get my custom url working, with ssl.  My url is registered with GoDaddy and I created a CloudFlare account for ssl without having to pay the $20/mo that Heroku charges.

I have the domain names added in heroku. I created the cname and cname flattening in the CloudFlare DNS and changed the nameservers from godaddy.  I have a full ssl certificate, which CloudFlare displays as active.  However, when I try to access the website, i get the following error:

SSL Connection Error: Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

I have gone through the faq on CloudFlare without success.  Can anyone help me out on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

==================================================

- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
- error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
- Closing connection 0 
  curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Comment: Hi sjagr, I have open tickets on both CloudFlare and Heroku.  I have a demo later this afternoon, so am stuck, and doubt will hear anything back from support quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately we're not going to help much faster than them - they have all of your information, configuration, and architecture. All we can do is guess - which is outside the scope of this platform. If the demo is that urgent, maybe you should cough up the $20 and point to Heroku directly for now.

Comment: Not sure if this means anything, but did a curl -v on the site and got this error:

Comment: also without the domain/site name in question it, it is really hard to provide any meaningful help,   as @sjagr said their support departments probably your best /quickest bet.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this worked for me:

**Step 1**

> Make a Cloudflare account, and add the bought domain to cloudflare and
>   transfer the DNS settings'

**Step 2**

> Add your domain to your heroku panel. On the heroku site, log in, go
>   to 'settings' press 'add custom domain'
>   `- Add both your domain 'www.example.com' and your root domain 'example.com'`

**Step 3**

> If you haven't changed your nameservers on your initial domain
>   provider to point to the cloudflare nameservers, please do so now. You
>   can find the cloudflare nameservers which are assigned to you on your
>   cloudflare panel under `'DNS' -> 'cloudflare name servers'`

**Step 4**

> Go to 'DNS' on your cloudflare account and `remove all records (A,
>   CNAME, ALIAS,TXT etc..).`
>   Now add  a `CNAME` record. The name should be your site '`www.example.com`' (with www) and it should point to your heroku app `example-example.herokuapp.com`

**Step 5**

> Create a Google Business account. And follow along with the
>   verification steps given by Google.

**Step 6**

> Log in at `admin.google.com` and go to '`domains`'. If you can't see
>   'domains' click on 'more elements'. Now click on '`change redirect`' and
>   make your root domain '`example.com`' redirect to '`www.example.com`'.

**Step 7**

> Go to your cloudflare panel and go to 'DNS', now `add 4 'A' Records`.
>   - All 4 of the 'A' records should have the name of your root domain  `'example.com'` and they should point to `216.239.32.21`,
>   `216.239.34.21`, `216.239.36.21`, `216.239.38.21`, which are the ip
>   addresses given by Google to make the redirects work.

*Side note*

> On cloudflare, the 'A' record statuses  need to be set to 'DNS Only'
>   and the 'CNAME' record statuses to 'DNS and HTTP proxy(CDN)'

**Step 8**

> On your rails app go to `production.rb` and make sure
>   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:
>   'https://example-example.herokuapp.com' }` is set to
>   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:
>   'example-example.herokuapp.com' }` so simply remove the 'https://'.
>
> And also `config.force_ssl` should be `false`
>
> **After you have done that make sure you upload the result to heroku.**

**Step 9**

> At cloudflare go to 'crypto' and make sure SSL is set to 'Flexible',
>   if not please change it now, it might take a few moments before the changes are completed by cloudflare.

**CONGRATULATIONS !!!!!!!!!!!!!**

> At this point your site should be up and running and working for both
>   your root domain aswell as for your full domain.

**EXTRA**

> *ONLY IF YOU WANT BUSINESS EMAILS BY GMAIL (eg. info@example.com)*
>
> On cloudflare go to 'DNS' and add `5 'MX' Records`.
>
> 1. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 1`
> 2. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt1.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 5`
> 3. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt2.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 5`
> 4. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt3.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 10`
> 5. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt4.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 10`
>
> **Note:** The `TTL` should be set to '`1 hour`' for `all 'MX' records`.

**Now go out there and be the best version of yourself!!**